# How to set a pivotX or pivotY on an ObjectAnimator defined in XML?

Tags: android, xml, animation

I have the following definition for an animation in res/animator/grow.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:ordering="sequentially">
     <set>       
       <objectAnimator
           android:propertyName="scaleX"
           android:duration="150"
           android:valueFrom="1.0"
           android:valueTo="1.5"
           android:valueType="floatType" />
       <objectAnimator
           android:propertyName="scaleY"
           android:duration="150"
           android:valueFrom="1.0"
           android:valueTo="1.5"
           android:valueType="floatType" />
     </set>
</set>
```

What I want is for the pivotX and pivotY to be in the center of the object, rather than the upper left hand corner. I know I could accomplish this via code, but I'd rather not do that. Instead, I'd like to specify it in the XML file. I thought about doing this:

```
<objectAnimator
  android:propertyName="pivotX"
  android:valueTo="50%" />
<objectAnimator
  android:propertyName="pivotY"
  android:valueTo="50%" />
```

But, this seems like it's going to try and animate that property as well, which is not what I want. Instead, I want it to set the pivots and then perform the animation. Can I do this in XML, and if so, how?

Comment: Hm... perhaps, given that this question has lingered so long, it's not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question without an answer and I didnt find an answer anywhere else, so I'll post my solution here:

**Logic:**

- in the start animation use a animation to set the pivot(s) to your desired values with a `duration=0`
- add `durations` to all other animations
- in the end animation reset the pivot(s) by using `startOffset` and `duration=0`

Optinally, don't use durations and don't reset the pivot... In this case, the pivot will just stay as it is, which in most cases is irrelevant.

**Code**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="0"
                android:propertyName="pivotX"
                android:valueTo="0" />

            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleX"
                android:valueTo="0.85" />

            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleY"
                android:valueTo="0.85" />
        </set>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <set>

            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleX"
                android:valueTo="1.0" />

            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleY"
                android:valueTo="1.0" />

            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="0"
                android:propertyName="pivotX"
                android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:valueTo="0" />

        </set>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define it (android:transformPivotX and android:transformPivotY) on your view (its a view's property now, not an ObjectAnimator's property).
Both are not % but sp,dp or px...

If you use VectorDrawable, it's a property of the group depending on the viewPort coordinates.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    >
    <group
        android:name="core"
        android:pivotX="12.0"
        android:pivotY="12.0">
        <path
            android:name="corepath"
            android:fillColor="#FF000000"
            android:pathData="@string/init_path_coreic_check_box_outline_blank_black_24dp"
            />
    </group>
</vector>
```

Or you can keep using the TweenAnimation

Answer (score 0):

basically you change a view property hence use transformPivotX and transformPivotY instead

this should do the trick:

```
<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="transformPivotX"
    android:valueTo="0.5"
    android:valueType="floatType" />

<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="transformPivotY"
    android:valueTo="0.5"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem for a fragment transaction. 
The annoying thing about setting it in the layout file's   `android:transformPivotX` is that it takes pixels while I want in percentage.

While not pretty you could add the value in the ObjectAnimator, example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="pivotY"
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>

</set>
```